# FM NMOR in Cesium with Atomic Density Matrix package

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to use the atomic density matrix package in Mathematica to simulate FM NMOR in Cesium. The example given in the package is for a specific system from J=1 to J'=0. I am trying to simulate for F=4 to F'=5 in Cs.

Any help on why I am getting no lock in rotation for Cs would help. The code is below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByijCC68ZEaOVjFtcFNnQlhfQlE/view?usp=sharing

The link to the package is below.
http://rochesterscientific.com/ADM/

Comment: A link to the package, and/or its documentation would be helpful.

Comment: @Sjoerd While the rule that the question should contain a link to the package stands, now it's easier to find packages like this by looking on http://packagedata.net/

Comment: @Szabolcs wow, since when is this a thing? (sorry for offtopic)

Comment: @shrx Maybe a month or so?  [Here's the chatroom.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29579/packagedata-net)  It was cerated by Pickett.  It's integrated with SE (you can use the same log-in).  It's still very much under construction.  If you know of any interesting packages, add them!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the Chop function was cutting the answer out.

I multiplied it by 10^36 and got the answer.